# How to use selection field (dropdown) instead of checkboxes in Odoo groups (roles) selection?

Tags: odoo

I am creating a custom module in Odoo for a faculty and y need to create 3 roles (groups): students, professors and admins. An user cannot have 2 roles at the same time, so it could only be either a teacher, a professor or an admin. I have defined the permisions in the following code. But for selecting those permissions, Odoo creates a view with checkboxes, where you can chose 2 or more roles at the same time, instead of a selection field (dropdown), I dont want that. How can I force Odoo to create a dropdown for the selection of those roles

[image]]

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_faculty">
    <field name="name">Faculty</field>
    <field name="description">Faculty Roles</field>
    <field name="sequence">45</field>
</record>

<record id="group_faculty_student" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Student</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
</record>

<record id="group_faculty_professor" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Professor</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
</record>

<record id="group_faculty_admin" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Admin</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<record id="group_faculty_student" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Student</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
    
<record id="group_faculty_professor" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Professor</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_faculty_student'))]"/>
</record>
    
<record id="group_faculty_admin" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Administrator</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_faculty"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_faculty_professor'))]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
</record>
```

But in that case all Professors also have Stundent group.

Comment: The proposed answer does not answer the question. The OP specifically stated the permissions were independent of each other.